# optimizations in distance based clustering with pandas and scipy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, geospatial

I wrote a distance based clustering algorithm using scipy KDTree and pandas. Its speed is sufficient for small datasets (samples < 100000 points). Are there any recommendations for optimization?

```
import cProfile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

def getRandomData(samples):
    points = np.random.rand(samples, 2) * 0.5
    data = pd.DataFrame(points, columns=['lat', 'lng'])
    # place points over Berlin
    data.lat += 13.1
    data.lng += 52.2
    return data

@profile
def clustering(tree, data, radius, centerMultiplier=0.5):
    """ Perform a simple distance based clustering. Add a column clusterNr to original dataset. """
    data['clusterNr'] = -1
    i = 0

    unclusteredIndexes = pd.DataFrame(data.index)
    while len(unclusteredIndexes.index) > 0:
        index = unclusteredIndexes.iloc[0][0]
        point = data.lat[index], data.lng[index]

        # get all points in half radius
        #clusterGroup = tree.query_ball_point(point, radius*centerMultiplier) # not present in scipy 0.11 and its not faster
        nn = tree.query(point, k=len(data.index), distance_upper_bound=radius*centerMultiplier)
        clusterGroup = list(np.sort(nn[1][nn[0] != np.inf]))

        # set found points to current cluster nr
        data.ix[data.index.isin(clusterGroup), 'clusterNr'] = i

        # get all points outside half radius and full radius
        #clusterForSecondStage = list(
            #set(tree.query_ball_point(point, radius)) - set(clusterGroup)
        #)      # not present in scipy 0.11 and its not faster
        nn = tree.query(point, k=len(data.index), distance_upper_bound=radius)
        clusterForSecondStage = list(set(np.sort(nn[1][nn[0] != np.inf])) - set(clusterGroup))

        # delete all indexes we found
        unclusteredIndexes = unclusteredIndexes[
            ~unclusteredIndexes.index.isin(clusterGroup + clusterForSecondStage)
        ]

        i+=1

    # build new tree with found clusters
    clusters = data[data.clusterNr != -1].groupby("clusterNr").agg(
        {'lat' : np.mean, 'lng': np.mean}
    )
    clusterTree = cKDTree(zip(clusters.lat, clusters.lng))

    # find nearest cluster for every non clustered point
    #tempData = data[data.clusterNr == -1]
    tempData = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[data.clusterNr == -1])
    tempData['_points'] = zip(tempData.lat, tempData.lng)

    def assignNearestCluster(x):
        return clusterTree.query((x[0], x[1]), k=1, distance_upper_bound=radius)[1]

    tempData.clusterNr = tempData._points.map(assignNearestCluster)
    del tempData['_points']

    # combine both datasets
    data = tempData.combine_first(data)
    return data

@profile
def clustering2(tree, data, radius, centerMultiplier=0.5):
    """ Perform a simple distance based clustering. Add a column clusterNr to original dataset. """
    data['clusterNr'] = -1
    i = 0

    unclusteredIndexes = sorted(data.index)
    while len(unclusteredIndexes) > 0:
        index = unclusteredIndexes[0]
        point = data.lat[index], data.lng[index]

        # get all points in half radius
        nn = tree.query(point, k=len(data.index), distance_upper_bound=radius*centerMultiplier)
        clusterGroup = list(np.sort(nn[1][nn[0] != np.inf]))

        # set found points to current cluster nr
        data.ix[data.index.isin(clusterGroup), 'clusterNr'] = i

        # get all points outside half radius and full radius
        nn = tree.query(point, k=len(data.index), distance_upper_bound=radius)
        clusterForSecondStage = list(set(np.sort(nn[1][nn[0] != np.inf])) - set(clusterGroup))

        # delete all indexes we found
        unclusteredIndexes = sorted(
            set(unclusteredIndexes) - set(clusterGroup) - set(clusterForSecondStage)
        )

        i+=1

    # build new tree with found clusters
    clusters = data[data.clusterNr != -1].groupby("clusterNr").agg(
        {'lat' : np.mean, 'lng': np.mean}
    )
    clusterTree = cKDTree(zip(clusters.lat, clusters.lng))

    # find nearest cluster for every non clustered point
    #tempData = data[data.clusterNr == -1]
    tempData = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[data.clusterNr == -1])
    tempData['_points'] = zip(tempData.lat, tempData.lng)

    def assignNearestCluster(x):
        return clusterTree.query((x[0], x[1]), k=1, distance_upper_bound=radius)[1]

    tempData.clusterNr = tempData._points.map(assignNearestCluster)
    del tempData['_points']

    # combine both datasets
    data = tempData.combine_first(data)
    return data

def main():
    samples = 1000
    radius = 0.1
    data = getRandomData(samples)
    tree = cKDTree(zip(data.lat, data.lng))
    clusters = clustering(tree, data, radius)
    clusters = clustering2(tree, data, radius)
    clusters['count'] = -1
    print clusters[clusters.clusterNr > -1].groupby("clusterNr").agg({
        'lat' : np.mean, 
        'lng': np.mean, 
        "count": "count"
    })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I profiled the code with the `line_profiler`. The results:

```
Total time: 0.066627 s
File: cluster.py
Function: clustering at line 14

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    14                                           @profile
    15                                           def clustering(tree, data, radius, centerMultiplier=0.5):
    16                                               """ Perform a simple distance based clustering. Add a column clusterNr to original dataset. """
    17         1          424    424.0      0.6      data['clusterNr'] = -1
    18         1            2      2.0      0.0      i = 0
    19                                           
    20         1          208    208.0      0.3      unclusteredIndexes = pd.DataFrame(data.index)
    21        22           68      3.1      0.1      while len(unclusteredIndexes.index) > 0:
    22        21         4035    192.1      6.1          index = unclusteredIndexes.iloc[0][0]
    23        21         4521    215.3      6.8          point = data.lat[index], data.lng[index]
    24                                           
    25                                                   # get all points in half radius
    26                                                   #clusterGroup = tree.query_ball_point(point, radius*centerMultiplier) # not present in scipy 0.11 and its not faster
    27        21         1580     75.2      2.4          nn = tree.query(point, k=len(data.index), distance_upper_bound=radius*centerMultiplier)
    28        21          639     30.4      1.0          clusterGroup = list(np.sort(nn[1][nn[0] != np.inf]))
    29                                           
    30                                                   # set found points to current cluster nr
    31        21        16911    805.3     25.4          data.ix[data.index.isin(clusterGroup), 'clusterNr'] = i
    32                                           
    33                                                   # get all points outside half radius and full radius
    34                                                   #clusterForSecondStage = list(
    35                                                       #set(tree.query_ball_point(point, radius)) - set(clusterGroup)
    36                                                   #)      # not present in scipy 0.11 and its not faster
    37        21         1888     89.9      2.8          nn = tree.query(point, k=len(data.index), distance_upper_bound=radius)
    38        21         1091     52.0      1.6          clusterForSecondStage = list(set(np.sort(nn[1][nn[0] != np.inf])) - set(clusterGroup))
    39                                           
    40                                                   # delete all indexes we found
    41        21           30      1.4      0.0          unclusteredIndexes = unclusteredIndexes[
    42        21         8064    384.0     12.1              ~unclusteredIndexes.index.isin(clusterGroup + clusterForSecondStage)
    43                                                   ]
    44                                           
    45        21           32      1.5      0.0          i+=1
    46                                           
    47                                               # build new tree with found clusters
    48         1         1213   1213.0      1.8      clusters = data[data.clusterNr != -1].groupby("clusterNr").agg(
    49         1         1934   1934.0      2.9          {'lat' : np.mean, 'lng': np.mean}
    50                                               )
    51         1          325    325.0      0.5      clusterTree = cKDTree(zip(clusters.lat, clusters.lng))
    52                                           
    53                                               # find nearest cluster for every non clustered point
    54                                               #tempData = data[data.clusterNr == -1]
    55         1          830    830.0      1.2      tempData = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[data.clusterNr == -1])
    56         1          849    849.0      1.3      tempData['_points'] = zip(tempData.lat, tempData.lng)
    57                                           
    58         1            3      3.0      0.0      def assignNearestCluster(x):
    59                                                   return clusterTree.query((x[0], x[1]), k=1, distance_upper_bound=radius)[1]
    60                                           
    61         1        18129  18129.0     27.2      tempData.clusterNr = tempData._points.map(assignNearestCluster)
    62         1          345    345.0      0.5      del tempData['_points']
    63                                           
    64                                               # combine both datasets
    65         1         3505   3505.0      5.3      data = tempData.combine_first(data)
    66         1            1      1.0      0.0      return data
```

I changed the code slightly and used a list to hold the unclustered indexes instead of a pandas DataFrame (clustering2). This speeds it up for around 25% for 1000 points. With more than 12500 points the pandas based version is 5% faster.

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but as a start you need to profile and highlight to us which part is slow

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there is a seperate page for reviews.

Comment: I don't necessarily think this is a bad question but it would help to profile your code and post the results